# Need help writing a dicitonary where the value comes from a file

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a dictionary where I create the key using for loops and then get the value for each key from a file.

My text file has individual lines like this for each of the 12 x 12 tables.

'I ate and I ate until I was sick on the floor, 8 x 8 is 64.'

I feel writing the rhymes like this in a txt document would be better than writing them in the python program.

I would then like to make a dictionary where the key follows this structure: 8 x 8 = 64

and the value is the whole sentence: 'I ate and I ate until I was sick on the floor, 8 x 8 is 64.'

To give further context, I basically have a list of incorrect answers from a game which follows the structure of: 8 x 8 = 64 (as illustrated above). This list is contained within a listbox in tkinter. So far, I have got my program to print the current selection from the listbox onto the console whenever the user selects an item e.g. 2 x 2 = 4.

I would like to have it so that when they choose a particular question/ key from the list (e.g. 8 x 8 = 64) next to it a label changes to the value of that question/key e.g. 'I ate and I ate until I was sick on the floor, 8 x 8 is 64.'

This would then give them help to remember the correct answer in future attempts at the game.

Below displays my code so far but yet again, I'm stuck! :(

```
d = {}
with open('help.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        val = line
        for i in range (1,13):
            for n in range (1,13):
                answer = n * i
                key = '{} x {} = {}'.format(n, i, answer)
            d [key] = val
```

I hope I've managed to explain my problem clearly. I'm open to other ways to do this too.

Comment: Will the two numbers on the left hand side always be the same? ie, `2 x 2` or `8 x 8` or do you want every combination?

Comment: @dawg, yeah, eventually. Although I do think there is little point thinking of a rhyme to help memorise very easy questions like 1 x 1 = 1

Comment: Something like: `['{} x {} = {}'.format(x,y,x*y) for x in range(1,13) for y in range(1,13)]`?

Comment: Your second for loop is wrong. No ident below and no colon.

Comment: @dawg, correct; my apologies! I have edited the post.

Comment: Show a sample of your file please. I think the problem is the opposite of what the answers are saying.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I haven't created the full file just yet because I'm not sure whether this is the best way to go about it. But it isn't complicated. Imagine separate lines in a text file much like this: “6 times 6 is 36, now go outside to pick up sticks.” "I ate and I ate until I was sick on the floor, 8 x 8 is 64."

Comment: @LMACK. I don't do well with hypotheticals. Please post the file that you are running in the example you show. Depending on the contents, your solution will be very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single for loop using `itertools.product` (for Cartesian products).

```
for line, (x, y) in zip(f, product(range(1, 13), range(1, 13))):
    ...
```

You could even do the whole thing in a dict comprehension like

```
from itertools import product
with open(help.txt) as f:
    d = {f"{x} x {y} = {x*y}": line.rstrip()
         for line, (x, y) in zip(f, product(range(1, 13), range(1, 13)}
```

This is assuming that the lines in your .txt file are in the same order as returned by product.

Consider reading the numbers from the .txt file instead of generating them programmatically. That way they're sure to match up properly. You can split a line of text using the `str.split()` method. See also, the `csv` module. The .csv format is simple enough to write by hand, and you can also export it from a spreadsheet program like Excel or LibreOffic Calc.

---

OK, here's a simpler approach. Since your values will be one-line strings, you can simply alternate key, value lines in your .txt file, like this.

```
8 x 8 = 64
I ate and I ate until I was sick on the floor, 8 x 8 is 64.
6 x 6 = 36
6 times 6 is 36, now go outside to pick up sticks.
```

You can read that into a dict like,

```
d = {}
with open('help.txt', r) as f:
    itf = iter(f.read().splitlines())
    for line in itf:
        d[line] = next(itf)
```

The `.read()` method will read the whole file at once as a string, then `.splitlines()` will split it into a list of lines (without the `'\n'`). The `iter()` function will get the iterator before the for loop starts (which the for loop can still use, since iterators are themselves iterable), and `next()` function will get the next item from the iterator, so you can read two lines per loop.

Comment: ,thank you for your help, but sadly your answer is beyond my coding know-how. I am quite a beginner. Could you possible elaborate?

Comment: I have just run your code. This is the output: {'8 x 8 = 64\n': 'I ate and I ate until I was sick on the floor, 8 x 8 is 64. \n'}... could you suggest a way to remove the new line syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem with your code is that you have nested loops. In English, your program reads something like this:

> For each line in the file, go through every combination of numbers, and add them to the dictionary.

This is clearly not what you want. You want one number or pair of numbers per line in the file. In the current version, you end up iterating over all the keys for each line, and overwriting the existing values. Your dictionary has all the right keys, but all the values are naturally the last line in the file.

This is a common problem for beginners. The solution is to have a single loop that steps through your numbers and the file in *lockstep*.

Let's look at a simple case first, with just the NxN rhymes. There are two basic options for implementing this. The first uses the `enumerate` function:

```
for n, val in enumerate(f, start=1):
    key = '{} x {} = {}'.format(n, n, n * n)
    d[key] = val
```

`enumerate` steps along any iterable, like a file, and yields a counter at every step. Another, more general, way to iterate two sequences in lockstep is using `zip`:

```
for n, val in zip(range(1, 13), f):
    key = '{} x {} = {}'.format(n, n, n * n)
    d[key] = val
```

There are some minor issues in your code too. For example, the line `val = line` is completely useless. Strings are immutable objects, and assignment does not copy the object, just makes a new reference to it. You can get rid of that line entirely. If you want the dictionary values to be called `val`, just write the outer door loop as `for val in f` instead.